# Creating Script to Automatically & Periodically Save Open (Focused) Files

Tags: scripts, libreoffice, automation

I would like a way of saving open files outside of the program in which they're open--a robust and simple way of doubly ensuring that highly important files are locally saved.

Would it be possible, then, to create a shell script I could run after opening a file in which the script automatically saves whatever file is in the focused window every five minutes?

For simplicity, this may mean only saving files that have already been saved (i.e., ones that do not need to have their file name and saved location specified), which is fine; in other words, the script could be equivalent to hitting S every 5 minutes for whatever program is currently focused on.

My personal interest is mostly for saving LibreOffice files, but if this can be made more general, this would be nice--both for me and hopefully for anyone else with similar concerns.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Not unless you would periodically virtually press Ctrl+S by e.g xdotool. That would be an unworkable situation though, and possibly interfere with what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's good to know. I'll simply have to look into other ways of backing it up (versioning, etc.)

Comment: @wes If you're basically asking about automating Ctrl+S shortcut press, then Jacob's suggestion is exactly what you want. If you have in mind backing up *already existing* file ( that is, not a new one you create in libreoffice, but something like providing an existing file to a commmand ), then there are other ways.

Comment: Thanks, @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Are you thinking of something that could back up an existing file that is currently open? I can edit my question (or ask a new one) indicating that my goal here is to provide a redundancy in file back-ups while files are being edited. (Does that clarify my goal here?)

Comment: @wes Yes, I was hinting at something that basically schedules copying the existing file at specific intervals of time. So, say you're working on a file, and there's a script in background that'll make a copy of it, with your desired time period ( 5 min, 10 min etc ).  Of course, this could be paired with Jacob's idea, too. Libre offic should have its own backup settings, but what I suggest can be made general, since it's just scheduling a copy.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That would be perfect--in fact, arguably preferable since creating a backup would not interfere with current editing or LibreOffice's own autosave function.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Think you could write an answer for this question ? I'm currently a little busy. See the comments  above for OP's requirements.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Unfortunately kind of the same here. Holidays are over :(

Comment: Thank you both anyway. I'll just make sure I hit save : )

Comment: Should I delete my question so it doesn't lay as litter in SE?

Answer (score 0):

In response to MS Autosave comments of people who hate MS Autosave because it immediately overwrites your document as soon as you make changes thereby deleting your previous iteration. Unless you have the foresight to make a copy before you make these changes, for example when you are updating a form to the new year.

I'm working on a script that I found online within MS Excel (I assume this would work in any version of Open Office as well) via a VBA module that does the following:

1. Saves a copy (and overwrites the old version) of your Excel spreadsheet upon 10 seconds of completion of a change you make to the spreadsheet. That is, after a pause of 10 seconds, or more, of the user adding data or text to a form. This is so it doesn't continually keep saving as you are actively typing data or text into the form.
2. Saves a new iteration of the spreadsheet every five minutes as long as a change has been made. This is ideal if you want to look back on your iterations for text or data that you may have deleted or reformatted in the process of where you are now with the form.
3. If desired a new iteration can be saved regardless if changes are made or not. This would show a timeline of activity and when it happened in the process.

These save intervals can be changed to your liking. And this script should work in any other Microsoft or Open Office document, such as Word, PowerPoint, Access, Publisher & possibly OneNote or their Open Office equivalents.

I found the following script online. This is a very basic start and I'm aware that it needs a lot of additional code. I am trying to fit this into my already very busy schedule. Any suggestions will be taken into consideration. I have tried a few different commands and it seems to be getting there. But what you think will work in theory is, of course another story in practice.

> Private Sub Workbook_Open()
>
> On Error GoTo Message
>
> Appication.AskRoUpdatezlinks = False
> ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
> ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> Application.DisplayAlerts = False
>
> ```
>   Dim currentTime As Date
>   currentTime = DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
>   
>   Application.OnTime currentTime, "SaveFile"
> ```
>
> Exit Sub
> Message:
> Application.DisplayAlerts = False
> Exit Sub
>
> End Sub

Thank You for reading this. I hope this helps someone (including me). I have been pulling my hair out for a while now trying to think of something that would work that isn't MS Autosave. Scripts seems to be the most reliable option if I can work the kinks out.

Sam